# Making a long string from each row

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, stored-procedures, varchar

I am trying to make a long string from comments and I created this sp

```
ALTER FUNCTION ugurcode.comment_summary
    (
    @opinionid int
    )
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
    BEGIN
    declare @cs nvarchar(max);
    select @cs+=comment+'\n' from fev_comment where opinionid=@opinionid
    RETURN @cs/* value */
    END
```

this returns null, how else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
declare @cs nvarchar(max);
```

with

```
declare @cs nvarchar(max) = '';
```

Concatenating `NULL` returns `NULL`.

BTW: Microsoft say "[The correct behavior for an aggregate concatenation query is undefined.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515/en-us)" and this approach can break. You might want to look at `XML PATH` instead (See [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)).

Comment: yes. solved. thanks. I'll mark as answer in 12 minutes (system allows after 12)

Comment: +1. Though op should be aware that this works for SQL Server 2008+.

Comment: @Lamak - The `+=` syntax is 2008 too.